# Are there any lightweight XMPP server?

Tags: 11.04, server, software-recommendation

Are there any lightweight XMPP server that works well on Ubuntu Desktop 11.04; I basically wanted to learn, test and develop some small application that uses XMPP features.

Answer (score 2):

### [Prosody](http://prosody.im/)

Available from the software center its claim to fame is "easy to set up and configure, and light on resources."

It appears to be actively developed - detail on the linked website.  The [PPA on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~prosody-dev/+archive/ppa) doesnt look like it is being maintained anymore - so perhaps avoid this and use the deb from the linked website for testing the latest version i.e. Natty is v0.7 whilst the current latest is v0.8.